# Android Naming Convention for getter method of boolean data type variable

Tags: android, naming-conventions

Getter method name for

```
private boolean mIsLast;
```

is

```
public boolean isIsLast() {
return mIsLast;
```

}

or

```
public boolean isLast() {
return mIsLast;
```

}

?

Should use isIsLast() or isLast()?

Comment: The best practice is not naming boolean variable like `isSomething`. Just `something`. If you will follow this practice then eclise will generate correct names for getters and setters.

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, a better answer to this would be to not use the "is" prefix in the variable name itself. Boolean variables should be named in such a way that prepending "is" would create a natural sounding question. So in OP's example, the field would be called mLast and the getter isLast().

Almost any other answer will say the same thing:

- [For a boolean field, what is the naming convention for its getter/setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322648/for-a-boolean-field-what-is-the-naming-convention-for-its-getter-setter)
- [setter for a boolean variable named like isActive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851337/setter-for-a-boolean-variable-named-like-isactive)
- [Java boolean getters "is" vs "are"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960554/java-boolean-getters-is-vs-are)

Answer (score 1):

`isLast` would be a preferable than `isIsLast` if you are dealing with boolean values. It is not a good naming convention to repeat the first syllables of the method.

Comment: Thank you. I also think isLast is more preferably. But, Android Eclipse IDE auto generate functions generated isIsLast. Can edit the IDE settings to generate isLast.

Comment: @BusCar Nope, you cant edit it from your IDE the only way is to change it when it is already auto generated your method, +1 and upvote this post if it helps thank you.

Comment: Sorry, @Rod_Algonquin. I would like to upvote. But, Vote Up requires 15 reputation. My reputation is only 11. I cann't vote up.

Comment: @BusCar you can still upvote just click the check mark